# Text inside of image

Tags: html, css

I just want to add my h2 text and small paragraph inside of my image like this way.

[image]

When I add h1 and texts, it's positioned under the image.

[image]

Is this happened for bad css positioning?

This is my code

```
<div className="committeeBackground">
                  <img src="/images/conference.jpg" alt=""/>
                  <h1>Who</h1>
                  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
                  </p>
                </div>

.committeeBackground{
img{
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```

Comment: You want them above or on-top?

Comment: Just like first picture. Middle of the image.

Comment: CSS cannot be nested like that. Also there is nothing in the code you supplied related to the positioning of any elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this, center it using `flex` and on top using `position: absolute`

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.ontop {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.ontop > div {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/animals/6" alt="">
  <div class="ontop">
    <div>
      <h2>Test Text</h2>
      <p><i>Dummy Text Under H2</i></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Working great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A common practice to do this would be to wrap everything in a `<div>` with the css `position:relative;` and then give the text elements the css `position:absolute;` to bring them on top of the image. Then you can use different attributes such as `top:0;` or perhaps `top:30%;` to bring the text down. If you want to keep all the text together, you could even wrap all the different text elements in a `<div>` and give that `<div>` the style `position:absolute;` and be able to move all the text together.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do what you're looking for:

I set the image to be the background of the div. And then i just worry about the inside elements.

```css
.backgroundImage {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/300?text=%20');
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block {
  display:block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="backgroundImage">
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Test Text</h2>
    <p><i>Dummy Text Under H2</i></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great! But I cannot use background images. I'm using react so I need to change the images

Answer (score 0):

You could put your image at **background-image**

```
<div className="committeeBackground">
              <img src="/images/conference.jpg" alt=""/>
              <h1>Who</h1>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
              </p>
            </div>
.committeeBackground{
   background-image: url("/images/conference.jpg");
}
```

Or use css > **position: absolute;**  to your child, and **position:relative** to your container div "committeeBackground"

```
    <div className="committeeBackground">
              <img src="/images/conference.jpg" alt=""/>
              <h1>Who</h1>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
              </p>
            </div>
.committeeBackground{
    position: relative;
}
.committeeBackground > * {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%
}
```